# Method descriptive name for a simple comparison or comparison directly?

Tags: java, coding-style

Sometimes there are comparisons very simples as equals, compareTo,... as next:

```
//Status is a String, and 
if(status.equals(StatusEnum.ACTIVE.value()) && dateRegister.isAfter(LocalDate.now)){
    //do something
} else {
   //do something
}
```

But I prefer to create a method with a more descriptive name although I use it once:

```
private boolean isActive(String status){
   return status.equals(StatusEnum.ACTIVE.value()) && dateRegister.isAfter(LocalDate.now);
}
```

And then:

```
if(isActive(status)){
    //do something
} else {
   //do something
}
```

Is a good idea or practice to create a method for such a simple comparison?

Sometimes I think I create a lot of methods to improve readability and there are people who do not like too much ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, what you are proposing here is the **better** style. What you are practicing there is one important aspect of **Clean Code**. And it is actually a great practice.

Reasoning behind it: your brain automatically spends time on "creating context". This means: when you are looking at source code, you immediately start to look for boundaries that help you understanding what is going on.

And in that sense, a small helper method for such checks (coming with a good name!) allows your brain to almost immediately grasp what is going on.

People who aren't used to this style often reject it initially. But the point is: when you ask them to read such code, they most often find it **easy** to read; although they practice a different style. They don't like what they see, but they have no problems reading it!

Compare that to the reverse experiment: when you start reading "their" code, in their style ... you quickly find that their code is harder to read. So does anybody else. Because your brain has to deal with "less" input. It gets worse: when people are used to read/write that other less-readable style ... what happens often is that they train their brain to **ignore such structures**. In other words: they accept the "bad style" ... because they are trained to **not look too closely**. Seriously, what could be worse than that?

Yes, in the end you might even have some "more" code to read; but the fact that it is so nicely structured still means: less efforts in the end.

And of course, the side effect here: if you don't put such code into utility methods, then people will start using copy&paste. Because you might need this check in more than one place. And that is where the real pain begins. Code duplication is never a good idea; and if it can be avoided by creating easier-to-read-code ... than that is exactly the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is very good practice!

What you're doing is called *abstraction*. You turn lower level stuff

```
status.equals(StatusEnum.ACTIVE.value() && 
    dateRegister.isAfter(LocalDate.now)
```

into higher level stuff:

```
isActive(status)
```

If I don't know much of your code, I will likely feel confused if I read your first piece of code. I will be like

> Ehh... what is this code doing? Why is it checking all this stuff for?

If I read your second piece of code, I would know that you're checking whether the status active, and more importantly, *the low level which I don't want to know is hidden from me*.

Another advantage is that you type less code. When you extract something as a method, the next time you want to do that "something", just call the method instead of duplicating that piece of code!

However, be careful when you do this. Be sure to name the method abstractly, but not too abstract, or too concrete. So these names don't work that great:

> parameterIsEqualToActiveAndDateRegisterIsAfterToday
>
> checkStuff

Answer (score 0):

Its not about simple or complex. If someone looks your code then he wont be able to understand what the if statement is checking but when you put that in a function and gave appropriate name, anyone can easily identify that if statement is checking whether the status is active or not. Creating functions makes the code simple, clean and understandable.